# Where to place gradle build file?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, gradle

Can someone please tell me where should I put gradle build file? In what directory (on windows 8.1)? I'm following some tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

But they didn't mentioned most basic thing - where to put that $^@*^ file?

Can someone suggest me some better tutorial to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under project root directory. On the same level as `src` folder. It's the most common scenario, when project has default structure - and that's the case here.